# Regex to create html anchor tag

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text field for user comments, a user may or may not insert a URL into this field.

e.g. they could have any of the following (plus other variations):

- Look at http://www.google.com some more text here possibly
- Look at https://www.google.com some more text here possibly
- Look at ftp://www.google.com some more text here possibly
- Look at http://google.com some more text here possibly
- Look at www.google.com some more text here possibly

What I want to do is match on these and change the string to include an HTML anchor tag.

Using the various other Stack Overflow answers about this subject I have come up with the below:

```
text = text.Trim();
text = Regex.Replace(text,
    @"((https?|ftp):\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,})",
    "<a target='_blank' href='$1'>$1</a>");
```

This works almost perfectly, it matches all the required patterns BUT when it matched against www.google.com (without the http(s)://) part, the anchor tag created isn't correct, the href of the anchor needs the http:// part or it creates the link as a relative url to the site.

How can I change the code above so that if the match doesn't contain the http:// part, it will add it to the href part of the anchor?

Interestingly, as I'm typing this question, the preview part is creating links out of my URLs above - all except my "trouble" one - the one without the http/ftp:// prefix.

Comment: Not a lot you can do about it. First step would be to try and find a ruleset (human readable) that works for all cases. Some people with a severe case of plenkitis often omit spaces which would result in strings like `end of sentence.new sentence`. In a case like that you wouldn't want to generate a link to `http://sentence.new`.

Comment: The reg ex will only pick up on www.someexample.com, i.e. with the www. prefix, and won't pick up on sentence.new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a match evaluator to check if Group 2 (`(https?|ftp)`) matched. If it did not, use one logic, else, use another.

```
var text = "Look at http://google.com some more text here possibly,\nLook at www.google.com some more text here possibly";
text = text.Trim();
text = Regex.Replace(text,
    @"((https?|ftp)://(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s.]+\.\S{2,}|www\.\S+\.\S{2,})", m => 
    m.Groups[2].Success ? 
       string.Format("<a target='_blank' href='{0}'>{0}</a>", m.Groups[1].Value) :
       string.Format("<a target='_blank' href='http://{0}'>{0}</a>", m.Groups[1].Value));
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/TaM92I), output:

```
Look at <a target='_blank' href='http://google.com'>http://google.com</a> some more text here possibly, 
Look at <a target='_blank' href='http://www.google.com'>www.google.com</a> some more text here possibly
```

Note I replaced `[^\s]` with `\S` everywhere in the pattern to make it look "prettier".

You may also remove the outer capturing group (and use `@"(https?|ftp)://(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s.]+\.\S{2,}|www\.\S+\.\S{2,}"` pattern) and then check if `m.Groups[1].Success` is true and use `m.Value` in the replacements.

Comment: Just trying to fully understand how this is working and the m.groups[2] part it confusing me - could you please explain it for a simpleton?

Comment: Your regex contains 2 capturing groups defined with `(...)`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r5zTLX/1).  The first one is an outer group capturing the whole pattern (in fact, it is not even necessary, the match value contains the whole match, or `Groups[0].Value`, or you can always access it via `$&` from the string replacement pattern), and the other is around `http`/`ftp`. If Group 2 matches, its `Succcess` property is set to *true*.